# Приставка «про-» в слове «продолжение»

Tags: словообразование, морфемный-разбор

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему в слове *продолжение* **про-** не является приставкой? Ведь корень **-долж-**.

Comment: Корень -продолж-. https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/продолжение. Корень -долж- в одолжении и -о- приставка: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/одолжение.

Answer (score 2):

Слова "***длинный, продлить, долгий, продолжить***" **исторически родственные**, да и в современном языке имеют **сходные значения**, связанные с временной или пространственной протяженностью.  **Но одного  этого недостаточно:** мы должны видеть не только одинаковые по значению **корни долг/долж,** но и подобрать **рабочую схему** образования слова, которая характерна для **современного состояния** языка.

Сравним два глагола: **про/дл/ить и продолж/ить.** Он могут быть взаимозаменяемыми, например: продлить (продолжить) линию до пересечения с окружностью, продлить (продолжить) каникулы до января.

Кажется, что они образованы по одной схеме, но существует глагол "длить(ся)", соотнесенный с прилагательным "длинный", но нет глагола «должить», соотнесенного с прилагательным "долгий".

Поэтому не работает схема образования **«долгий — продолжить» с использование приставки ПРО** и нужным нам значением (увеличить длительность чего-либо).

Comment: Как всегда интересный и подробный ответ!

Answer (score 0):

-долж- долг, доля, дол (устар. долина), до (предела)...
-про- сквозь, через, можно и эту часть разложить...

приставка/корень/суффикс/окончание (в корне бывает вставка, беглые)

prefix/fix/suffix/postfix (infix)

приставка (пред_ставка) / ставка (в войну - генштаб) / су_ставка (сустав в теле, супесь, суглинок) / пост_ставка (блокпост, пост охраны, т.е. на удалении от ставки)     (вставка - в корень слова)

вся эта конструкция - только слегка удачная попытка систематизации языков, по_этому иногда появляются "умозаключения" на подобие: "у некоторых слов нет корней"

словари пишут люди, основным свойством которых, то_же является "ошибка" и собственные желания

вообщем, окончательный выбор только за вами

Comment: Один может ошибиться, поэтому там работает коллектив.